# Unable to determine schema of SELECT * in this query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have created a table in Bigquery using the data personsData.json and schema personsDataSchema.json provided by the documentation at https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested.

This query works fine:

```
SELECT children.* FROM dw_test.persons
```

But the following query gives the error `Error: 0.0 - 0.0: Unable to determine schema of SELECT * in this query`:

```
SELECT citiesLived.* FROM dw_test.persons
```

I understand that a workaround will be to simply list all the fields of citiesLived:

```
SELECT citiesLived.place, citiesLived.yearsLived FROM dw_test.persons
```

But in the case when the record has many fields, listing all the fields becomes cumbersome.

Could anyone please help?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have a failing job ID? Or can you provide the project id?

Comment: The failing job ID is vindicogroup.com:healthy-skill-488:job_MybJP4iAcH9nW7hPDpUZ3Y-_htw

Comment: Thanks ... we're investigating. This looks like a bug.